# how to convert pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d method to keras or tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, spatial-pooling

I don't know how to convert the PyTorch method `adaptive_avg_pool2d` to Keras or TensorFlow. Anyone can help?
PyTorch mehod is

```
adaptive_avg_pool2d(14,[14])
```

I tried to use the average pooling, the reshape the tensor in Keras, but got the error:

> ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but in PyTorch, you pass the spatial dimensions to [`AdaptiveAvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d). For instance, if you want to have an output sized 5x7, you can use `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((5,7))`.

If you want a global average pooling layer, you can use `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)`. In Keras you can just use [`GlobalAveragePooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalaveragepooling2d).

For other output sizes in Keras, you need to use [`AveragePooling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#averagepooling2d), but you can't specify the output shape directly. You need to calculate/define the `pool_size`, `stride`, and `padding` parameters depending on how you want the output shape. If you need help with the calculations, check [this page of CS231n course](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#pool).

Comment: yes, I want to get the same with with Pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d using keras, for example, adaptive_avg_pool2d(X, [14,14]) will output 14,14,2048, but the original shape is 21,45,2048, I want to reshape it to 14,14,2048 using keras code. Thankyou.

Comment: Another, the output shape is always the same, 14,14,2048, no matter how the input shape. Any good suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You may use the information of the previous layer and define the pooling layer based on that info.

Comment: Thank you,  Fábio Perez. Sorry, I am not familiar with pytorch and keras. Would you please give a specific example. Currently, I am using resnet101, original shape is 21,45,2048, Using pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d(X, [14,14]), the output shape is 14,14,2048. so I am using AveragePooling2D((3, 3), name='avg_pool')(x) in keras, the shape changed to 7,15,2048, need change shape to 14,14,2048.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, it is great help, Fábio Perez

Comment: you can create a custom layer on top of the AveragePooling2D layer for that purpose