# Pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d algorithm

Tags: pytorch, pooling

Anyone knows the algorithm for pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d, for example,

```
adaptive_avg_pool2d(image,[14,14])
```

so question:
    I want to do the same in keras neural network, for any give inputs, want to get 14*14 output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert pytorch adaptive\_avg\_pool2d method to keras or tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622518/how-to-convert-pytorch-adaptive-avg-pool2d-method-to-keras-or-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this exists in Keras. You could get the dimension of your input and divide by 14 to get the desired pool_size.

For example if your inputs are 28x28 you can use:

`keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None)`